# React native - problem with launching app on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with React native and running the app on Android(runned by yarn).
Console doesn't tell me much :(

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 42s
25 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 22 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to start the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n com.theoplayerreactnative/com.theoplayerreactnative.MainActivity
    at makeError (C:\Users\mKochman\Dev\theo\reactnative-app\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

So app built, installed on the real device but couldn't launch it :(

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "npm:react-native-tvos@0.62.2-1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fxied that XD
What was needed in my case:

- gradle update,
- set env path for adb(Windows)
- clear all builds
- system restart